# Is there a method to show progress (round circle) below the last item in RecyclerView while following page data is downloaded?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I am creating app in which I implemented endless scroll to `RecyclerView`, but when I get to the bottom of the first page the app hangs until the next page's data is downloaded. After downloading it starts working. Is there any method to show progress (round circle) below the last item in `RecyclerView`, and after downloading the next page's data the round progress circle disappears and our next page will get displayed below?.

Request item class code is below.

```
public class RequestItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
List<ParseObject> parseObjects;
List<FeedItem> feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
int skip=0;
ProgressBar progressBar;

RequestItems(Context context,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    eventsRecyclerView=null;
    Loadmore(eventsRecyclerView);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    final EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView=new EventsRecyclerView(context,feedItems);
    int spacingInPixels = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing2);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));
    LinearLayoutManager manager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScroll(manager, context) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            Log.d("amar", "requestitem");

                    skip = skip + 6;
            Loadmore(eventsRecyclerView);
            //  eventsRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(eventsRecyclerView);
}

private void Loadmore(EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
    query.setSkip(skip);
    query.setLimit(6);
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    try {
        parseObjects = query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!parseObjects.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parseObjects.size(); i++) {
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Title"));
            item.setDate(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Date"));
            item.setTime(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Time"));
            item.setVenue(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Venue"));
            item.setLike(parseObjects.get(i).getBoolean("Like"));
            ParseFile file = parseObjects.get(i).getParseFile("EventImage");
            try {
                byte bytes[] = file.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,100,150,true);
                item.setEventImage(bitmap1);
                feedItems.add(item);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (eventsRecyclerView!=null){
            eventsRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

and my `EndlessScroll` class code is below

```
public abstract class EndlessScroll extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
public static String TAG = EndlessScroll.class.getSimpleName();

private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
int count=0;
Context context;
int count2=0;
private int current_page = 1;

private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

public EndlessScroll(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager,Context context) {
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        // End has been reached
        // Do something
        current_page++;
        onLoadMore(current_page);
        loading = true;
    }
}

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

Comment: I've tidied up this post considerably, edit anything back if it has lost its original meaning in any way.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your project for me it works

```
private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
private int currentVisibleItemCount;
private int currentScrollState;
private int totalItemCount;
private int mNumOfAllBooks;
```

and this in when you instantiated your listview

```
 mLoadingMoreFlag = false;
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            currentScrollState = scrollState;
            if (currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == (mAdapter.getCount() - 1)) {
                    if (totalItemCount != mNumOfAllBooks) {
                        if (!mLoadingMoreFlag) {
                            mLoadingMoreFlag = true;
                            loadMore();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
            currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
        }
    });
```

and in loadmore:

```
 private void loadMore() {

    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   ....
}
```

just put mProgress in bottom of the layout and listview in your xml;